# watchOS 8 - SwiftUI adding additional, unwanted space around Image

Tags: swiftui, watchos, watchos-8

When using watchOS 8, there is unwanted space/padding around my Image. I measured it and it's 6 logical pixels on each side. How can I get rid of it?

This is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59449381/swiftui-generates-unwanted-space-around-an-image), because I'm not using a HStack/VStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be gone when using the `Image(uiImage:)` initializer.